# general question about ner/spacy with pdf/docx files and their text position

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm looking into ner/spacy and have a more general answer.
we actually do ocr with pdf documents where we generate a json file with positions and text blocks/paragraphs. currently we are looking into ner/spacy to analyze the text know and check if we can find out if a specific paragraph looks like an address or something.

however what we did not understood is if it is possible to also feed the position data to spacy, or if it makes more sense to feed the text block/paragraphs one by one and ignore the position, however most often in these structued documents the position is important since it also tells us if it is a address or not.

so can spacy understand these documents?

I'm pretty sure that we are more likely need to go to the route of using vision to detect the paragraphs and this will classify our data and ner will than be used for the paragraphs to recognize the text (hence the name ner)

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way to pass extra data to spaCy models at the moment, so it's generally not a good fit for using position data like in OCR. However there is a workaround and it's not too bad. See [this section](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226#:%7E:text=i%20want%20to%20add%20non-textual%20features) in the FAQ.

Basically you'll need to override the `Doc` creation functions to add a feature which can then be passed to downstream models. You'll also have to customize the downstream model, but again that shouldn't be too complicated.